# Bizarre SSH Problem - It won't even start

Tags: ssh, openssh

I recently got Ubuntu 12.04 Precise, got it up and running with some MediaWiki software, static IP on the box and router and was able to access the main page even from a cell phone. Everything seemed great...

Then I wanted to finally get rid of the monitor and keyboard and login remotely via SSH.

I installed openssh-server, let everything point to port 22 for a test run and installed putty on my Windows XP machine. I got a connection refused. Went back and started checking the Ubuntu install itself... (I'm under root from this point on)

```
$ sudo -s

$ service ssh status
ssh stop/waiting

$ service ssh start
ssh start/running, process 2212

$ service ssh status
ssh stop/waiting
```

Apparently ssh has stopped or is waiting for something....

```
$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

I can't even connect to myself... I checked ufw (firewall) to see if port 22 is doing alright...

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
To        Action        From
22        ALLOW         Anywhere
22/tcp    ALLOW         Anywhere
22        ALLOW         Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp    ALLOW         Anywhere (v6)
```

`sshd_config` shows only Port 22

Is ssh not using the right IP address at all? I just don't get what I did wrong here. When this is up and running I will def change the port number, but for now, I don't want to mess with the default install too much until a test run with putty is successful.

**Edit:**

Here are my [sshd_config](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1284630/) file and my [ssh_config](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1284635/) file.

The command `/usr/sbin/sshd -p 22 -D -d -e` returns:

> /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 159: Subsystem 'sftp' already defined.

**Edit:**
@phoibus
moving the sshd_config file and reinstalling did the trick!

## service ssh status

the above command shows that ssh is now running and I am now able to log in from my windows xp computer remotely via putty. Thanks so much! I can now use my monitor for other things!

Comment: Can you post your ssh `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on pastebin (http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and edit you question to contain the link?

Comment: Stop the sshd service and run the sshd in standalone debug mode: `/usr/sbin/sshd -p 22 -D -d -e`. Try connecting and see what happens.

Comment: Glad that it worked! Please remove your answer since you posted the information in your post and accept my answer to mark the question as solved.

Comment: if this is happening in all users, make sure you are following this doc https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring especially check this doc, the part about /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key in this doc http://askubuntu.com/questions/485777/openssh-server-is-refusing-connections-by-blocking-or-resetting.

Comment: Note that according to sshd_config's man page, this error should not exist, but sshd should just ignore multiple definitions of directives. See also this upstream bug report: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3236

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You got duplicate sections in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Rename your `sshd_config` file

```
sudo mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.old
```

and reinstall `openssh-server` to get the original file:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssh-server
```

See if it works now.

Answer (score 6):

My issue was also a setting issue, but I couldn't figure out which of my changes was the problem. After digging a little you can run `sshd -t` and any `sshd_config` errors will be reported.

`root@sh1:/etc/ssh# sshd -t
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 102: Directive 'UsePAM' is not allowed within a Match block`

Which means 'Match blocks' settings need to be at the end of the `sshd_config` file.

Comment: my error is : `missing privilege separation directory: /var/run/sshd` what now?