# SSH to network alias ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: networking, ssh

New install: `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-45-generic x86_64)`

I have no problem with SSH to the DHCP address `.22`, but when I try the alias address `.80` the connection is reset by peer.  I've done no other setup other than a new installation and setup of the network alias.  `ufw` is not enabled and there is nothing in the `hosts.deny` or `hosts.allow`.  I have tried deleting the `known_hosts`, none of which changed the result.  I have enabled sshd_config `LogLevel DEBUG`, but `/var/log/auth.log` doesn't provide any information about the connection attempt that is reset.

/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

```
alias {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 10.1.10.80;
}
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:60:00:a6:02:9e  
          inet addr:10.1.10.22  Bcast:10.1.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca60:ff:fea6:29e/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:484:c301:c400:ca60:ff:fea6:29e/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1465 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:551715 (551.7 KB)  TX bytes:260772 (260.7 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:fb700000-fb720000 

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:60:00:a6:02:9e  
          inet addr:10.1.10.80  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:18 Memory:fb700000-fb720000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

Success on SSH to 22

```
kross$ ssh -v 10.1.10.22
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/kross/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.10.22 [10.1.10.22] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/kross/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/kross/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kross/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kross/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA be:5f:04:6c:62:a6:bd:28:57:ec:63:43:c0:9c:eb:b9
debug1: Host '10.1.10.22' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/kross/.ssh/known_hosts:28
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/kross/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kross/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Failure when trying to SSH to the alias fixed IP

```
kross$ ssh -v 10.1.10.80
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/kross/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.10.80 [10.1.10.80] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/kross/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/kross/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kross/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kross/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

---

**Subnet mask**

So based on a [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485777/openssh-server-is-refusing-connections-by-blocking-or-resetting), I noticed the alias mask is `.255` instead of `.0`.  I tried setting options to see if that changed anything, but the value would not change.  I have another ubuntu server setup the same way, and it looks the same (the alias mask also is `.255`, so perhaps this isn't a problem.

---

**ListenAddress**

I tried changing the `ListenAddress` in sshd_config, with nothing changing.  It seems as though this config is for restricting access, instead of the default which listens on all addresses.

---

**netstat**

```
# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.10.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.1.10.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.1.10.80      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: I also tried `apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server openssh-client`

Comment: Perhaps related, note my netmask is different on the aliased interface http://askubuntu.com/questions/485777/openssh-server-is-refusing-connections-by-blocking-or-resetting

Comment: Sometimes when I have this error it helps if I remove server's line from `.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning **ListenAddress**.  Would you mind being more specific as to what you have it set to currently?  Also, sorry, but have you restarted `sshd` since you've added the interface?

Answer (score 1):

So, step 1 to setting a fixed ip address should be to make sure another device isn't already connected to that ip!  The moment I changed the ip to something that wasn't already claimed, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check `man sshd_conf`, it says, in part:

```
 ListenAddress
         Specifies the local addresses sshd(8) should listen on.  The following forms may be used:

               ListenAddress host|IPv4_addr|IPv6_addr
               ListenAddress host|IPv4_addr:port
               ListenAddress [host|IPv6_addr]:port

         If port is not specified, sshd will listen on the address and all prior Port options specified.  The default is to listen on all local addresses.  Multi‐
         ple ListenAddress options are permitted.  Additionally, any Port options must precede this option for non-port qualified addresses.
```

So I suggest you add `ListenAddress 10.1.10.80` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

`sshd` in the 2nd case, is not "listening" on that IP address, so denies the connection.

Comment: Added, restarted ssh and networking, first attempt to login yielded `write: Broken pipe`, second attempt to login yielded `ssh: connect to host 10.1.10.80 port 22: Connection refused`, third and later attempts yielded `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.   I have another ubuntu server with a similar setup and I didn't have to add the ListenAddress, so I'm not sure this is the right direction but I gave it a shot.  The man page states `The default is to listen on all local addresses`.

Answer (score 0):

For reference [this](https://codeplanet.io/connection-reset-by-peer/) worked for me.

In `/etc/hosts.allow` add `sshd :ALL`