# ssh'ing from one computer to another on the same subnet

Tags: ssh, remote-access, nmap

I have two computers connected to the same subnet.

The first (A) is running 14.04, the second (B) 12.04

I can ssh from the first to the second, but not from the second to the first.

Don't really know where to start to figure out why there's this difference.

However nmap is giving quite different results:

Computer (A), which is the one I *can't* get into:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
631/tcp open  ipp
```

Computer (B), which I can get into:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
53/tcp  open  domain
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp open  ipp
```

Since the only port that's open on both is 631, I've tried ssh'ing from B to A specifying port 631, but that doesn't work either.

Could anybody please advise how to proceed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How are you connecting? Are you using an IP or a hostname? Can you ping the machine you can't connect to? Try connecting with `sshh -vvv user@host` and post the output here.

Answer (score 1):

Install `openssh server` on `PC A`.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

More details you have [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring)

Then you will can `ssh` into `PC A` from `PC B`

`SSH` work on `port 22`.

Edit 1

If you have installed `ssh-server` on PC A you can check with command `netstat -at` do
server expect connection on `port 22`

This is output from my PC

```
xxx@xxx:~$ netstat -at
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:microsoft-ds          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:netbios-ssn           *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ipp                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:telnet                *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0    320 xxxx:ssh              xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:43423    ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:microsoft-ds       [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:netbios-ssn        [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ipp                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       1      0 ip6-localhost:38900     ip6-localhost:ipp       CLOSE_WAIT
```

Important is:

```
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
```

If you set `ufw` or some `firewall` disable it and try connect then.

Also restart `ssh` service

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

You will see if service start.

Comment: ssh is installed and is running on both machines, and /etc/ssh/sshd_config on and  the /etc/ssh/sshd_config files are identical on both machines.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add:   the message I receive when I try to log into PC A is "connection refused"

Comment: I add Edit 1 to answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much for your responses.   I finally resolved this problem, thanks to the very helpful thread

[Bizarre SSH Problem - It won't even start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201995/bizarre-ssh-problem-it-wont-even-start)

The problem was that in the version of sshd_server that I downloaded with

```
apt-get install sshd_server
```

There were three lines at the bottom of the sshd_config file that was installed, which proved to be the source the problem

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11   yes
```

When I removed these lines my remote login problems were resolved.    To diagnose the problem, I followed the suggestion in the above thread, which suggested closing sshd with

```
service sshd stop
```

then running in debug mode

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -p 22 -D -d -e
```

In debug mode, sshd flagged the bad options in the default sshd_config file.

After removing these lines, and restarting, port 22 was open.